# Realm DB library adds around 3.5 Mb

Tags: android, realm

Before adding ream library support my app size was 2.55MB and after adding realm size became 6.43MB.
Version used : 0.87.5
Tables created only 2 . with 3 rows each table.
is it really adding that much ?

Comment: if you want it to be much faster than sqlite, you have to pay in apk size... btw is sqlite really that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike SQLite which is shipped with the platform, Realm comes with its own native libraries. This means that the app size unfortunately increases. You can use ABI splits as described here to bring that number down to about 1MB (by building an app for each CPU architecture):

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/gridViewExample/build.gradle#L30-Lundefined